# How to view all of the private Windows of an active Safari session?

Tags: macos, safari

Suppose one has 400 tabs open across 25 Windows in Safari on macos. The majority of these are not private so it is fairly cumbersome to cycle through all of the available open windows to find all of those that are private Windows. Of course the non private ones are not an issue because one is not liable to lose them upon rebooting a computer, however I believe that the privates are not stored anywhere persistently so they would be lost and if one wishes to preserve them before rebooting one's system, you would have to find and record their states manually in some way.

I'm wondering if there any simple way either through Apple script or even something even easier to automatically list or even call forth all currently open private browsing Windows in current version macos Safari.

Comment: You can certainly walk all the tabs, I'm not sure whether you can easily tell from Applescript whether the windows are private or not as that's internal to the browser.  Interesting experiment, will have to look at that.

Comment: Perhaps the window titles parenthetically indicate when Windows are private browsing ones?